# `rescue_from` an exception only if format is json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have an application in rails that can respond both to json and html.
I'd like that, when a record returns an error while saving, the json answer is like that:

```
{
  "errors" : {
    "slug" : [
      "can't be blank"
    ],
    "title" : [
      "can't be blank"
    ]
  }
}
```

So I added this code to my `ApplicationController` class.

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid do |exception|
  render json: { errors: exception.record.errors },
         status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

I'd like that this `rescue_from` is called only when the format is json, otherwise behave in the standard way (when the format is html). How can I do something like this?

**UPDATE**
I found a solution, but I don't think that it's very good:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid do |exception|
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      render json: { errors: exception.record.errors },
           status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
    format.html { fail exception }
  end
end
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: instead of rescuing from that exception, you should not raise it in the first place. that's what `.save` and `.errors` are for. if you use a `respond_with` call, rails will automatically return a `unprocessable_entity` status and the errors as json

Answer (score 3):

There is a better approach.

For example:

```
  rescue_from ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken do |exception|
    raise unless request.xhr?
    render nothing: true, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
```